# Why Kotlin jvmToolchain does not set jvmTarget?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

In my `build.gradle.kts` I have:

```kotlin
kotlin {
    jvmToolchain {
        this.languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
    }
}
```

However, when I moved to Spring Boot 3.0 I noticed that I need to specify `jvmTarget` as well:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}
```

Is there a way to declare `jvmTarget` in kotlin/jvmToolchain block?

Comment: Another question I have is what is the intended difference between `jvmToolchain` and `jvmTarget`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was a bug. https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/issues/2511

If you're using a later version of Kotlin multiplatform plugin (maybe 1.8+?), you should only have to specify this in one place.